# LibreOffice: Color world map based on spreadsheet

Tags: libreoffice

A few times I wanted to color a world map based on values in a spreadsheet.

Is there some way I can do that?

In general I will have a spreadsheet with 2 columns: Country and value. But I can often calculate a color based on the value.

Is there a way I can visualize this on a map using LibreOffice? Maybe connect the spreadsheet to an SVG file of the world in LibreDraw, so that the color of each country comes from the spreadsheet?